# unix clear out content from files without deleting any directory

Tags: unix

I have a directory "ADir" containing recursively some directories .

What unix command can I run to make sure

```
1) directories are not deleted AND 
2) NO file is deleted
3) all the files currently present contain only one data and that is 0
```

and what will be command for

```
1) directories are not deleted AND 
2) NO file is deleted
3) all the files currently present are  emptied out
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `find(1)`:

1. with `echo 0 > {}`: (`{}` is replaced with matched file path)

   ```
   find ADir -type f -exec sh -c "echo 0 > {}"  \;
   ```
2. with `> {}`:

   ```
   find ADir -type f -exec sh -c "> {}"  \;
   ```

**UPDATE**

For larger numbers of files, use a single shell instance:

```
find Adir -type f | while read path; do echo 0 > $path; done

find Adir -type f | while read path; do > $path; done
```

Comment: @HenkLangeveld, Numbered list (without content after the number) works well with indented code block. I rolled back.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld, Thank you for the comment. I added your comment to the answer.

Comment: There must be something wrong with my browser then (chrome, linux), as I don't see the intended effect. I just see each list index and item on separate lines.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld, [Here's what I see](http://i.imgur.com/nBPFvj4.png) (Windows 7, Chrome). displayed similarly in chromium, linux.

Comment: That's exactly what I see.  Not how a numbered list normally gets rendered.  I just prefer the numbered list layout, but it's not a big issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47590/discussion-between-henk-langeveld-and-falsetru)